# Sequence diagram Combined Fragments

Tags: uml, diagram, sequence-diagram

I'm still figuring out sequence diagrams and I'm wondering if I've depicted what I wanted correctly.

the user sets a certain number(id) of announcment in the search bar of the main page. If you have not entered it, the catalog page opens, if you have entered it, then we search by the number in the catalog. Here the loop works out and we look through each catalog announcment, if we find it, then we break the cycle and display the page of the announcment we are looking for, if there is no announcment with such a number, just open the catalog page.

I'm not sure I was able to display the loop correctly.I'm not sure how to portray the fact that I view every announcment in the ad catalog. (the announcment is an object). I will be grateful for adjustments and recommendations.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A loop repeats while the condition is true. Therefore, `[for each an]` is not a good condition. The `search()` operation could return a status, that is checked in the condition (e.g. `[status!=last entry]`. If you want to avoid such technical details, you could use `loop (no_of_announcements)`. The general notation is `loop(min,max)`. If you only provide one value, it is used for both the minimum and maximum number of repetions.

Speaking of `search()`. It seems more likely, that you want to interate through the complete list of announcements instead of searching for a specific one. So a better name would probably be `next()`.

The break fragment leaves conditionally the immediatly enclosing fragment. In your case that would be the alt fragment. Also, it doesn't have a condition. You probably wanted to have the break fragment enclosed in the loop fragment and having `[an_num found]` as a condition.

In each loop you are potentially displaying the `CatalogPage`. I guess, you wanted to display the page only after iterating through all of the announcements without success. A better place to do that, would be in an opt fragment *after* the loop.

It is just a matter of taste, but I would prefer to see how the condition is changed by return values of the `search()/next()` operation. You could assign it to a variable: `status=next()`.

Another issue: Messages cannot cross the border of fragments. So all your fragments must be wider to include the recipient of the message.